# IWebBrowser2 control does not resize

Tags: winapi, webbrowser-control, activex, iwebbrowser2

I have created a simple Win32 application that embeds the browser control.  I handle WM_SIZE on the host window as follows:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    RECT rc = { 0 };
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    ::MoveWindow(hWndChild, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, TRUE);
    return 0;
```

I also handle WM_SIZE on the control window as follows:

```
    case WM_SIZE:
       ...
       IOleInPlaceObject* pl;
       ax->OleObject->QueryInterface(IID_IOleInPlaceObject, (void**)&pl);
       RECT r;
       GetClientRect(ax->Site.Window, &r);
       pl->SetObjectRects(&r, &r);
       pl->Release();
       return 0;
```

If my initial navigation is set to, say, http://www.microsoft.com, things work as expected. I can resize the host window which in turn resizes the browser control.

However, when I navigate to https://login.live.com, the control just does not resize as shown in the following figure:

[image: Browser does not resize]

Can someone please guide me on what is it that I am missing? Regards.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem site resizes correctly in a normal browser?

Comment: Try handling `DWebBrowserEvents2::WindowSetResizable` and other `WindowSet*` events.

Comment: The site does resize in a normal browser. The site is heavily used for authenticating via Windows Live ID.

Comment: Noseratio. WindowSetResizable seems to be just a hint to the host. What is it that must be done here?